# CountDown Timer to release date

Tags: swift, timer, release

Hi I am trying to handle this code and my problem is on part of code:

```
countdownTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: (Any).self, selector: #selector(updateTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

is this error message in Xcode

> Argument of '#selector' cannot refer to global function 'updateTime()'

And I am unable to handle this.
what could be wrong ? thank you

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
var releaseDate: NSDate?
var countdownTimer = Timer()

func startTimer() {

    let releaseDateString = "2019-02-23 08:00:00"
    let releaseDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    releaseDateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    releaseDate = releaseDateFormatter.date(from: releaseDateString)! as NSDate

    countdownTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: (Any).self, selector: #selector(updateTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func updateTime() {

    let currentDate = Date()
    let calendar = Calendar.current

    let diffDateComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: currentDate, to: releaseDate! as Date)

    let countdown = "Days \(diffDateComponents.day ?? 0), Hours \(diffDateComponents.hour ?? 0), Minutes \(diffDateComponents.minute ?? 0), Seconds \(diffDateComponents.second ?? 0)"

    print(countdown)
}
```

Comment: I dont like to answer link only but have you watch this ? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=82SXeAmZwk8

Comment: Why do you use global functions and don't put it all in a class. Maybe I didn't understand your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can’t use global function in `#selector`. So move this into a class. Plus, if you’re going to use selector-based timer, `updateTime` must be marked as `@objc`.

Alternatively, if you really want to use global functions, just use the block-based timer:

```
var releaseDate: Date?
var countdownTimer = Timer()

func startTimer() {
    let releaseDateString = "2019-02-23 08:00:00"
    let releaseDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    releaseDateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    releaseDate = releaseDateFormatter.date(from: releaseDateString)

    countdownTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { _ in
        updateTime()
    }
}

func updateTime() {
    let currentDate = Date()
    let calendar = Calendar.current

    let diffDateComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: currentDate, to: releaseDate!)

    let countdown = "Days \(diffDateComponents.day ?? 0), Hours \(diffDateComponents.hour ?? 0), Minutes \(diffDateComponents.minute ?? 0), Seconds \(diffDateComponents.second ?? 0)"

    print(countdown)
}
```

But it would be better to put this in a `struct` or `class` to avoid polluting your global namespace.

(Plus, I’m not sure why you use `NSDate` ... I’d suggest staying with `Date` objects.)

---

Personally, I’d do something like:

```
class TimerManager {
    var releaseDate: Date?

    private weak var countdownTimer: Timer?

    private let formatter: DateComponentsFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
        formatter.unitsStyle = .full
        formatter.allowedUnits = [.day, .hour, .minute, .second]
        return formatter
    }()

    deinit {
        countdownTimer?.invalidate()
    }

    func startTimer() {
        releaseDate = DateComponents(calendar: .current, year: 2019, month: 2, day: 23, hour: 8).date

        countdownTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { [weak self] _ in
            self?.updateTime()
        }
    }

    private func updateTime() {
        guard let releaseDate = releaseDate,
            let string = formatter.string(from: Date(), to: releaseDate) else { return }
        print(string)
    }
}
```

This not only takes care of the `Timer` issues, but also gets you out of the business of manually building those formatted strings of the components of the date difference.